# Count active and print active session starting with a specific string

Tags: php

Hi is there a way to count active and print active session starting with a specific string?

For example, I want to count session that has a name starting with "question"

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by `session`? They don't typically have a name so maybe you're talking about something else?

Comment: php sessions? as in $_SESSION `session_name()`? Those would have whatever name you told PHP to use.

Comment: I'm referring with global variable $_SESSION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that we are using the `$_SESSION` array and the names are done similar to:

```
$_SESSION["question1"] = "foo";
$_SESSION["question2"] = "bar";
...
```

Loop through the array and check if `"question"` is inside each string by using [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php):

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) 
    if(strstr($key, "question"))
        print $value;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I think this is what I'm looking for I'll test this..thanks again